# Load BigQuery.source_table into another BigQuery.target_table through stored procedure using google cloud Dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gitlab-ci, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Use case: Load BQ to BQ load using dataflow (Can be anything in dataflow(apache beam,pipeline,job template)

The stored procedure is to insert the source BQ data into target BQ table.

The source BQ data is fetch through query which is present in *.SQL files inside which it is calling some stored procedure and then through that stored procedure it is inserting the data into another bigQuery target table

below are the scenario files:

file1_task1.sql :

```
DECLARE query_to_load string;
DECLARE col_name string;
set col_name = 'empid,empname,deptid';
set query_to_load = '''(SELECT empid,empname,deptid from project_id.dataset.emp_source1 )''';
CALL`project_id.dataset.sp_table1`('project_id','dataset','emp_target1',query_to_load,col_name,NULL,NULL);
```

sp_table1:

```
BEGIN
IF truncate_table is  NULL THEN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE `project_id.dataset.emp_target1`;';
 END IF;
IF destcolumndetail is NOT NULL THEN
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' INSERT INTO `project_id.dataset.emp_target1`(empid,empname,deptid)
 SELECT empid,empname,deptid from project_id.dataset.emp_source1;';
```

file2_task2.sql :

```
DECLARE query_to_load string;
DECLARE col_name string;
set col_name = 'empid,empname,deptid';
set query_to_load = '''(SELECT empid,empname,deptid from project_id.dataset.emp_source2 )''';
```

CALL `project_id.dataset.sp_table2`('project_id','dataset','emp_target2',query_to_load,col_name,NULL,NULL);

sp_table2:

```
BEGIN
IF truncate_table is NULL THEN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE `project_id.dataset.emp_target2`;';
END IF;
IF destcolumndetail is NOT NULL THEN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO`project_id.dataset.emp_target2`(empid,empname,deptid)
SELECT empid,empname,deptid from project_id.dataset.emp_source2;';
```

I want to run in a sequence -- sp_table1 >>sp_table2
Could anyone please provide code or suggestions.

Comment: You want to call the `sp_table1` then `sp_table2` procedure before to launch the Dataflow job ?

Comment: Through dataflow only ...create a dataflow which load sp_table1 and then sp_tsble2.,please let me any code using dataflow

Comment: Have you a DAG orchestrator for your pipelines like Airflow ?

Comment: Yes I did through dag but want to through dataflow only as need to execute multiple sql files along with that need go perform complex etl data processing..so composer is not recommended here..thats why want to see an approach through dataflow.please let me know through dataflow if can do the same

Comment: If you have to execute to some process or queries in sequence, Airflow is more adapted for that. It’s better to delegate this responsibility to the DAG orchestrator then perform the Dataflow job with a more easy approach.